# JFrame and visibility: issue with fading out and getting a screenshot

Tags: java, swing, jframe, screenshot, visibility

In an action (i.e. a method) executed by pressing a button deployed into a `JFrame`, I want to hide the java app and then to get a screenshot. Finally, once the screenshot is taken, I need to make the `JFrame` visible.

The method is the following:

```
  public void myButtonPressedAction(){
       //Hiding the JFrame
       this.setVisible(false);
       //Now I use Robot to get a screenshot using another method
       //not reported for simplicity
       myMethodToGetScreenshot();
       //Making the JFrame visible
       this.setVisible(true);
  }
```

What happens is that, once visibility is set to false, the app starts to become invisible and immediately I get the screenshot: unfortunately, the screenshot also capture the `JFrame` while fading out (i.e., it is going to become invisible, the `isVisible` method returns `true`,  but the `JFrame` is not completely invisible).

One possible solution is to insert a timer to put a delay between the call to `setVisible(false)` and the one to `myMethodToGetScreenshot()`. However, suppose that the system is busy, the delay could be undervalued; on the contrary, a larger delay will make my application slow!

How can I get the exact time instant such that the `JFrame` has been completely fade out, i.e. it is really invisible?

**EDIT**

This are initialized in the constructor:

```
String myPath= ...;//here I have a String that represent a path to a folder.
JPEGImageWriteParam JPEG_PARAMS_BEST_QUALITY = new JPEGImageWriteParam(null);
JPEG_PARAMS_BEST_QUALITY.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
JPEG_PARAMS_BEST_QUALITY.setCompressionQuality(1f);
```

This is the code for  `myMethodToGetScreenshot()`:

```
public void  myMethodToGetScreenshot(){
  BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenArea);
  ImageWriter writer = writerService.getWriter();
  writer.setOutput(new FileImageOutputStream(new File(myPath+"screenshot.jpg")));
  writer.write(null, new IIOImage(capture, null, null), JPEG_PARAMS_BEST_QUALITY);
}
```

This is the screenshot I get. You can see the JFrame fading out...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `setvisible` you can use `setExtendedState`

```
//Minimize the JFrame
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
//Now I use Robot to get a screenshot using another method
//not reported for simplicity
myMethodToGetScreenshot();
//Restore the JFrame
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
```

Comment: As I said, after the call to `setVisible(false)` the `isVisible` method returns `true`

Comment: Nothing changed! The screenshot still capture the JFrame while fading out. I don't know if the fading is controller by Java or by the OS!

Comment: `I don't know if the fading is controller by Java or by the OS!`..It is controlled by OS.See my update..I hope this would be of your help

Comment: Great! This solution is really smart!

Answer (score 3):

Then put some delay time. You can use [Swing timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Here is a small demo:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ScreenshotDemo {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton("Catch the screenshot");
    Timer timer;
    Robot robot;
    JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public ScreenshotDemo() {
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Keeps frame disposed for 3 seconds
        timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Rectangle size = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                        .getScreenSize());
                Image image = robot.createScreenCapture(size);
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                timer.start();
            }
        });

        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(1024, 768);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ScreenshotDemo();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Basically, you will hide your frame for some time (3 seconds in this demo). While frame is hidden you will take a snapshot.

Comment: This was the first solution that came into my mind, as you can read from my question. There are some drawbacks in this approach, as I pointed out. Thank you, however!

Comment: @mat_boy Thats a working solution, which I just tested. Just put your code in Timers actionPerformed method (before frame.setVisible(true)) and voila!

Comment: +1 for the effort. I think that [Gabriel Negut](http://stackoverflow.com/users/619252/gabriel-negut) answer is more elegant. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a reasonable delay after hiding the frame and before taking the screenshot. Easiest way is to insert a call to [`robot.delay()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#delay%28int%29) before [`robot.createScreenCapture()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).

Comment: I just said that using a times is a possible solution, which I would to avoid (imagine what happens when the machine is busy and thus slow). However,  your answer is similar to the one provided by [brano88](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1324709/brano88) but it is more compact. I like it!

Comment: +1 for the compactness of the answer. If none will answer this question without using times, I will accept this one!

Answer (score 0):

I'd give the **ComponentListener** a try (assuming this code goes to a member of a JFrame-extending class):

```
    final Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    ComponentAdapter componentAdapter = new ComponentAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            myMethodToGetScreenshot();
            contentPane.removeComponentListener(this);
        }
    };
    contentPane.addComponentListener(componentAdapter);
```